# Sikuli click. (ScreenCaptureImage) in java

Tags: java, sikuli

I am new to Sikuli and I wanted to

```
1. click windows button, and 
2. type "Helloworld"  
3. press Enter.
```

I have coded this and working Successfully in Sikuli IDE

```
click("1391583846712.png")
type("helloWorld")
wait(2)
type(Key.ENTER)
```

I tried to move this to Java , 
From the sikuli javadocs I have seen the following code, However it is not working in java sikuli-api-1.0.2  and latest version

```
import org.sikuli.script.*;

public class TestSikuli {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Screen s = new Screen();
            try{
                    s.click("imgs/win-start.png", 0);
                    s.wait("imgs/spotlight-input.png");
                    s.type(null, "hello world\n", 0);
            }
            catch(FindFailed e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
```

}

It tells that Screen is an interface . Please tell me how to make it working in latest java sikuli-api. Please see that I am very new to Sikuli . Any suggestions will be highly appreciated. Also Please point me to the right sikuli java for begineers

Comment: If you are new to something try to read the documentation or manual.

Comment: documentation is outdated for java sikuli api.

Comment: Try to add direct import to `org.sikuli.script.Screen`.

Comment: Latest Sikuli Java API doc.:   http://doc.sikuli.org/javadoc/

Answer (score 0):

`new org.sikuli.api.DesktopScreenRegion()` creates a `ScreenRegion` on the base full screen where you can click and seek your images

Your best bet to find how the new API is built is to look at [the sources](https://bitbucket.org/doubleshow/sikuli-api). There aren't a lot of classes to understand, fortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The following Sikuli Java code should work:

```
import org.sikuli.script.*;
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Screen screen = new Screen();
        try{


screen.click("D:\\Sikuli\\WinStartButton.png");
```

//"WinStartButton.png" must exist on the desired location you are using
//OR, instead of above line you can use the following:

```
screen.type(Key.WIN);

        }
        catch(FindFailed e){
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
        screen.type("Hello World");
        screen.type(Key.ENTER);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have used my absolute image path. Please use your image path instead

Comment: It's better to create an image folder in Project and ust it as all images folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use image locator in your code,

```
import org.sikuli.script.*;

import org.sikuli.basics.ImageLocator;

public class AuthLogin {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Screen s = new Screen();
ImageLocator.setBundlePath("path to img directory");
        try{
                s.click("win-start.png", 0);
                s.wait("spotlight-input.png");
                s.type(null, "hello world\n", 0);
        }
        catch(FindFailed e){
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use the absolute image path directly in the code.
I would create a class which contains the absolute paths as static constants.

Example :

instead of :

```
screen.click( "D:\\Sikuli\\WinStartButton.png");
```

you can do it like this :

```
public static final String IMAGE = "D:\\Sikuli\\WinStartButton.png";

screen.click(IMAGE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Keydown and Keyup method for Enter key pressed
I have tried to organize the entire code. please let me know if its working.

```
   Screen sikuli = new Screen();
   String message = "hello world";
   Pattern imgLocator = ""; 
   if(sikuli.exists(imgLocator)!=null) {
        sikuli.find(imgLocator);
        sikuli.click(imgLocator);
        sikuli.wait(2);
        sikuli.type(imgLocator, message);
    }
     
    sikuli.keyDown(Key.ENTER);
    sikuli.keyUp(Key.ENTER);
```